# spring rest get error 500

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller

I've an app and I use rest. When I try to access rest url, I get error 500.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public @ResponseBody List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userService.getAllUsers();
}
```

and in my config, I have this

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

can you help me? thanks in advance

Comment: 500 means "internal server error". So you got an error, and the stack trace should be returned and/or logged in the server logs. Read the stack trace. Post it if you can't understand it.

Comment: the project use maven-tomcat and the only log I found contains:
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [27/Sep/2015:11:56:04 +0400] "GET /market/admin/dashboard/all HTTP/1.1" 500 997 http-bio-8080-exec-5 127

Comment: be sure to properly configure logging. enable spring classes logging. Try to isolate your code rwturning an empty collection from getAllUsers(). btq be more graceful to the message converter returning a Collection instead of a List: you would not have any List functionality aynway on the client side of your rest call.